# Changing the email recipients email based on branch deployed in email-ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

The  **Email-ext plugin** works great when it comes to sending the email.

To implement the conditions to match before sending the email ,I found it has the feature to write presend scripts. But I cannot find the proper documentations for how to write the script.

***My requirement:***

> If the branch being deployed is master or develop than I want to use
>   one set of email recipients else other set of emails.

**Provide me the right way to get going with the scripts**

1. Can we write bash script there
2. Can we use the variables set in bash script to the presend script

Comment: There are two straightforward options: (1) use two separate builds, (2) preferred: use the Jenkins `Multibranch Pipeline` build and commit branch specific configuration directly into the corresponding branch source code

Comment: @OlegSklyar but with Multipbranch Pipeline we will have large numbers of branches deployed as there might be large number of branches in bitbucket when there is large number of developers  working beside master and develop right so in that case that might be horrible right if I am correct

Comment: You can use regexp to exclude all branches that you do not want in the job spec. We use it to include all release branches + master + dev, but exclude all feature branches. Granted you can find a regex that suits you

Answer (score 1):

2) you can use any variables you want, Jenkins env variables or any variable you add with the help of "env inject" plugin.

Regarding your question:

> If the branch being deployed is master or develop than I want to use one set of email recipients else other set of emails

Example:

1)execute shell step in post build actions

```
if [ $BRANCH == "develop" ];then
   echo DEV_RECIPIENTS=dev1@mail,dev2@mail,dev3@mail > recipient.txt
else
   #assuming only master branch is left
   echo MASTER_RECIPIENT=master@mail,master2@mail > recipient.txt
fi
```

2) Using EnvInject Plugin, add step "Inject environment variables"
    and specify previously created recipient.txt

Now you can use DEV_RECIPIENT or MASTER_RECIPIENT( depends on branch built)
by ${DEV_RECIPIENT} or ${MASTER_RECIPIENT}

3) just paste this variable in extEmail step field "Recipient List": ${DEV_RECIPIENT}

Comment: i cant find the options `execute shell` in the Post-build Actions steps of jenkins. Also may be its not safe to use  ENVInject plugin as  the warning clearly appears on its installation page

Answer (score 1):

**Looks complicated but this is how I solved it:**

**preSend Script:**

```
if ("develop"=="${BRANCH_TAG_NAME}" || "master"=="${BRANCH_TAG_NAME}") {
          recipients = msg.getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO)
          msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, "email1,email2")
        }

     else{
recipients = msg.getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO)
msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,"email2,email3")
    }
```

**Where:**

BRANCH_TAG_NAME is the branch-name whose value is being set in bash script. Looks like we can easily access the variable defined in bash script to the preSend script.